# Magento get product ids from orders separated by comma

Tags: php, magento

I need to get productID(s) from an order and display this way:
[1234, 7534, 4587]

I am able to get the product IDs this way:

```
$incrementId = "12345";
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount= count($items);
$meuproduto = array();
$i=0;
foreach($items as $itemId => $item) {
  $meuproduto[$i]['id'] = $item->getProductId();
    echo implode(", ", $meuproduto[$i]);
}
```

For example this order had products 2709 and 7048, so I would like to display:
[2709, 7048]

But with the code I have it's showing:
27097048

I have tried `str_replace("", ", ", $meuproduto[$i]);`, but I get same result. I tried different ways, but always with same result.

```
print_r($meuproduto[$i]);
```

results:

```
Array ( [id] => 2709 ) Array ( [id] => 7048 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your echoing out each product rather than the list of products, so put the echo outside of the loop.

You are also never changing `$i`, so it will always write to the first element of the array, you can just use `[]` to add an item to the end of an array...

```
$meuproduto = array();
foreach($items as $itemId => $item) {
  $meuproduto[] = $item->getProductId();
}    
echo implode(", ", $meuproduto);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Folowing code

```
$meuproduto = array();

foreach($items as $itemId => $item) {
      $id = $item->getProductId();
      array_push($meuproduto,$id);

}
print_r($meuproduto);
```